# getAqi() in HMS Weather Awareness always returning null value

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

In HMS Weather Awareness getting null value while using getAqi() which is used to obtains AQI information, including the CO, NO2, O3, PM10, PM2.5, SO2, and AQI value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqi info is only supported in China